# Creating periodic/looping workflows

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I have a list named reminder_list which has a `DateTime` field called reminder date. 
I want to create a SharePoint designer workflow on that list which will run everyday and check if the reminder date field is equal to current date or not,if it is equal then it will send an email.

Is this possible to do? Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using SharePoint Workflows. You should use Custom Timer Jobs instead, see: http://www.andrewconnell.com/Creating-Custom-SharePoint-Timer-Jobs
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2010-Custom-416cd3a1

Comment: i have used timer jobs for this but i don't want a timer job this time my requirement is a substitute for timer job. Any ideas.Also someone has told me one can use retention policies with workflows for doing this

Comment: Could you use SharePoint Designer Activity "Pause Until" and define that Date as a parameter?